# How Memcached ensure that its pages in memory wont be swapped out by other pages?

Tags: c++, caching, web-applications, memcached, scalability

So I am trying to speed up my database-driven website and I came across memcached which I can apparently use to "cache" frequent key/values from the database in the memory. My question is, how can data be forced to stay in the memory, because normally if the server is running other application, there is a possibility that the memcached hashtable (or part of it) will be written back to the hard disk if a page from another application replaces a page from the memcached. So in industry, do they have separate machines that only run the memcached? or do they tweak the operating systems internals so that pages from the memcached wont be swapped out?

The question can be generalized to any other application, knowing how to force data to stay in the memory can be very beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

By default memcached pages will be swapped out to the hard disk if your machine is using more physical memory than it has available. You can specify the -k parameter however to specify that the pages memcached is using be locked into physical memory with mlockall(). See this blog post for more information on how to do this.

http://threebrothers.org/brendan/blog/using-memcached-k-prevent-paging/

Answer (score 0):

The OS writers have written good algorithms for paging over the years; algo that have stood the test of time. The paging algorithm tries to optimize the pages it swaps out.

'it would be very beneficial to to force the data to stay in memory' - sure about that? Would you rather have your Apache code being swapped out, rather than a page of data that was not used for an hour? If Apache swaps out, who would use that data?

It is difficult to design something that beats native OS paging algo. Can be done, but usually requires more than just locking memory for 1 program.

I would recommend setting memcache size appropriately so that the machine does not use paging.

If you run memcache solely on the system, which many people do, there is not much need to fiddle with -k switch. Or that machine can be set to swap = 0.